# HighStock - Custom chart type

Tags: customization, highcharts

Is it possible to create your own chart type in HighStock? Standard chart types in HighStock (OHLC, CandleStick etc. ) are not suitable for my application. The aim is to represent data in an another way. Please help with some suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: I've looked at several JS charting libraries, tried basic examples for standard chart types. At present stopped at Highstock to get in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Always you can prepare your own serie, based on wrapping highcharts functions, but we have no type of chart.

Howto wrap functions: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Could you plz have a look at the chart type that I need? [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uwdYZLi9tbNvH3SzfucQxNP13TBs6S5-PpsuRauvKNs/pub)  Basically its the same as OHLC or candlesticks. There are no top or bottom "whiskers". Each bar consists of several rows. Row contains price and some technical data

Comment: Plz check the chart in jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fh76/q2tpF/). Each bar has a red dot under it. Now try to zoom in, new bars are drawn with new red dots under each of them but old dots do not vanish. How can I remove old dots on each update. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. What I want to do is to split each columnrange bar into three separate rows, each row indicates 0.25 movement. This can be achieved by rendering a border and two horizontal lines in between. [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uwdYZLi9tbNvH3SzfucQxNP13TBs6S5-PpsuRauvKNs/pub). As I am new with Highcharts, I started with rendering dots on the series. Your solution gave me a new idea. Maybe I should add a new marker in prototype.symbols  that takes the coordinates of the bar and draws the lines on each bar? Hope I am in the right direction.